# Python Return Statement Doesn't Work

Tags: python

```
def palindrome(String):  

    result = ""    
    String1 = String ; String2 = String[::-1]
    print(String1) ; print(String2)
    if String1 == String2:
        result = String1       
        #print("re ",result) 
        return result        
    else:
        String = String[1:]
        palindrome(String) 

String = "aaaabbaa"
print(palindrome(String))
```

Comment: The one return statement you have works just fine. You just don't return anything in the else branch.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `return palindrome(String)` in your `else` to pass the result up the stack and out.